# Adding Array data to curl post fields

Tags: php, parsing, curl

This is the post fields of a CURL request. I need to add multiple county ids to this CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS: -

```
CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => '{
  "fields": [
    {
      "field_type": "countries",
      "field_value":[

        {
            "country_id": '.$id.' ,
            "match_type": "exact"
        }
        ]
    }
  ]
}'
```

I have an array of country ids and need to create this block for all: -

```
{
                "country_id": '.$id.' ,
                "match_type": "exact"
            }
```

so that If I have 5 country id's it should look like

```
CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => '{
      "fields": [
        {
          "field_type": "countries",
          "field_value":[

            {
                "country_id": '.$id[0].' ,
                "match_type": "exact"
            },
            {
                "country_id": '.$id[1].' ,
                "match_type": "exact"
            },
            {
                "country_id": '.$id[2].' ,
                "match_type": "exact"
            },
            {
                "country_id": '.$id[3].' ,
                "match_type": "exact"
            },
            {
                "country_id": '.$id[4].' ,
                "match_type": "exact"
            }
            ]
        }
      ]
    }'
```

The number of countries may vary each time. So I need to use a for loop inside this to do it dynamically.
Thanks in Advance

Comment: What is the the problem then?

Comment: he wants to do it programatically i guess.. So with a foreach loop

Comment: The number of countries may vary each time.So I need to use a for loop inside this to do it dynamically

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this.

```
$id = array(1,2,3,4,5,6); // Your IDS
$numberOfIds = count($id);  //Total number of ids (no comma after last entry)  
$finalString = ""; // The final string for output.
foreach($id as $key => $value){

    $finalString .= '{
            "country_id": '.$value.',
            "match_type": "exact"
        }';
    if($key < $numberOfIds-1){
       $finalString .= ","; 
    }
}

$curlStuff = '{
  "fields": [
    {
      "field_type": "countries",
      "field_value":[
            '.$finalString.'

        ]
    }
  ]
}';
var_dump($curlStuff);
```

Will give

```
string(681) "{
  "fields": [
    {
      "field_type": "countries",
      "field_value":[
            {
            "country_id": 1,
            "match_type": "exact"
        },{
            "country_id": 2,
            "match_type": "exact"
        },{
            "country_id": 3,
            "match_type": "exact"
        },{
            "country_id": 4,
            "match_type": "exact"
        },{
            "country_id": 5,
            "match_type": "exact"
        },{
            "country_id": 6,
            "match_type": "exact"
        }

        ]
    }
  ]
}"
```

So you could run

```
CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $curlStuff;
```

Answer (score 3):

It is extremely ill-advised to try to manually craft a json string in a loop.  You should be building a valid array then converting it to json when you are done.

To build your desired result array, just push new data into the appropriate subarray.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/AHCoA))

```
$country_ids = range(1,5);
$result['fields'][0]['field_type'] = "countries";
foreach ($country_ids as $id) {
    $result['fields'][0]['field_value'][] = ["country_id" => $id, "match_type" => "exact"];
}

var_export($result);
echo "\n---\n";
echo json_encode($result, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);  // this resembles your posted data
```

Output (as both array and json):

```
array (
  'fields' => 
  array (
    0 => 
    array (
      'field_type' => 'countries',
      'field_value' => 
      array (
        0 => 
        array (
          'country_id' => 1,
          'match_type' => 'exact',
        ),
        1 => 
        array (
          'country_id' => 2,
          'match_type' => 'exact',
        ),
        2 => 
        array (
          'country_id' => 3,
          'match_type' => 'exact',
        ),
        3 => 
        array (
          'country_id' => 4,
          'match_type' => 'exact',
        ),
        4 => 
        array (
          'country_id' => 5,
          'match_type' => 'exact',
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ),
)
---
{
    "fields": [
        {
            "field_type": "countries",
            "field_value": [
                {
                    "country_id": 1,
                    "match_type": "exact"
                },
                {
                    "country_id": 2,
                    "match_type": "exact"
                },
                {
                    "country_id": 3,
                    "match_type": "exact"
                },
                {
                    "country_id": 4,
                    "match_type": "exact"
                },
                {
                    "country_id": 5,
                    "match_type": "exact"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```